# Auto/ Cinematic Scroll Text Box Effect CSS/ JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a simple variant of the text box auto scroll on hover as seen [here](https://www.deviantart.com/literature/whats-hot/). When you hover over a box, the text scrolls.When you mouse out, the text resets to the beginning. That's all I'm after.

There appears to be a similar question: [Auto scroll text effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827762/auto-scroll-text-effect). However, the example link isn't working (at least for me) and I can't say definitively if it is the same as what I'm after or not. Also that question assumes a jquery environment. I'm working with native JS.

I'm not sure if JS is needed for this, html/css solutions are welcome too. Let me know what I can bring to bear for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an exact question like yours see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073780/vertical-autoscroll-on-mouseover-like-deviantart-com-project-giveaway-has).

You might also want to see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873753/make-table-auto-scroll-vertically-via-html-css) as well.

About scrolling with [marquee](https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/scrolling_text.cfm), [start/stop](https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/stop_marquee.cfm).

**Sample:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>My Example</title>

<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" id="mymarquee" scrollamount="1" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
<p>This the the sample</p>
<p>of my text</p>
</marquee>
```

**Lengthy paragraph**:

```css
#mypara {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<title>My Example</title>

<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" id="mymarquee" scrollamount="1" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
  <p id="mypara">This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.This the the sample.</p>
</marquee>
```

Comment: cool, thanks for the references. I'm curious to experiment with a lengthy `<p>` instead of a new `<p>` for each line. My guess is it would work with some styling.

Comment: @ArashHowaida yes, i edited the answer abit with a small example.

Answer (score 2):

You can give the text box or div a class like:

```
  .mydiv:hover {  
    animation: scrolling 12s .2s linear 1;
  }


  @keyframes scrolling {
    from { top: 0; transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
    to { transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0); }
  }
```

You might need to give it some `overflow: auto;` and `overflow-x: hidden;`

Answer (score -1):

```
div = document.getElementById("whatever_your_textboxes_id_is")

div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer.